# Remove Woocommerce Side Nav on Checkout Page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the side bar on the Woocommerce checkout page that displays the "Billing details" and the "Payment confirmation" links.

When I inspect the element it says: ul class="woocommerce-side-nav woocommerce-checkout-nav"

I've tried css and some changes to the function.php file with no result. With css I managed to hide the text but it would still take the space on the page.

Comment: Could you provide some code?